# How to send some messages/request to facebook users from php

Tags: php, facebook

I have number of facebook user_ids,sending by a user(his friends user_id)
I have to send message/app request to all of them.
How can I do that ?

Is there any tutorial or solutions..please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

facebook developers have sample scripts (for php too). Have you tried [this](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/464/), for instance ? 
An pp generated sample request in php is  as follows

```
<?php 

  $app_id = YOUR_APP_ID;
  $app_secret = YOUR_APP_SECRET;

  $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" .
    "client_id=" . $app_id .
    "&client_secret=" . $app_secret .
    "&grant_type=client_credentials";

  $app_access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

  $user_id = THE_CURRENT_USER_ID;

  $apprequest_url ="https://graph.facebook.com/" .
    $user_id .
    "/apprequests?message=’INSERT_UT8_STRING_MSG’" . 
    "&data=’INSERT_STRING_DATA’&"  .   
    $app_access_token . “&method=post”;

  $result = file_get_contents($apprequest_url);
  echo(“Request id number: ”, $result);
?>
```